# Cannot enable I2C

Tags: pi-3, sensor

I am following this tutorial [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ccs811-air-quality-sensor/raspberry-pi-wiring-test) to connect my CCS811 sensor with my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. They ask you to enable I2C after running `sudo raspi-config` and going into the Advanced Options. However, when I do the same, I only see this in the Advanced Options:

[image: My Advanced Options screen]

Where is I2C? And how can I enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its under 'Interfacing Options' then 'I2C':

[image]

[image]